# Arcpy Error 000732 Failed to Execute (TabletoTable)

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

I know this is a duplication, but I have read all the other answers on the forum and haven't gotten any solution.

**This is my code:**

```
#Import environment settings
import os, sys, string
import arcpy

#Define Environment
arcpy.env.workspace = "Database Connections/TRANSCO_OEDEVT.sde/"
#Define connections
OEDEVT_SV = "Database Connections/TRANSCO_OEDEVT.sde/"
SQLDEVGIS = "Database Connections/DEV_SQLDEVGIS.sde"


#Check to see if any tables for write operation exists already, delete them if so
if arcpy.Exists(SQLDEVGIS + "\R_TRANSCO_PIPES"):
    print "R_TRANSCO_PIPES exists, deleting now"
    arcpy.Delete_management(SQLDEVGIS + "\PUBLISH.RISK.R_TRANSCO_PIPES")

#Define Tables
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(
    "Database Connections/TRANSCO_OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV",
    "in_memory",
    "R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV",
    "#",
"""PODS_EVENT_ID "PODS_EVENT_ID" true false false 8 Double 0 16 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,PODS_EVENT_ID
            ,-1,-1;MANUFACTURER_CODE "MANUFACTURER_CODE" true true false 254 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,MANUFACTURER_CODE
            ,-1,-1;DATE_MANUFACTURED "DATE_MANUFACTURED" true true false 36 Date 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,DATE_MANUFACTURED
            ,-1,-1;MATERIAL_CL "MATERIAL_CL" true true false 254 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,MATERIAL_CL
            ,-1,-1;PIPE_SPECIFICATION_CODE "PIPE_SPECIFICATION_CODE" true true false 254 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,PIPE_SPECIFICATION_CODE
            ,-1,-1;PIPE_GRADE_CODE "PIPE_GRADE_CODE" true true false 254 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,PIPE_GRADE_CODE
            ,-1,-1;NOMINAL_DIAMETER_CODE "NOMINAL_DIAMETER_CODE" true true false 254 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,NOMINAL_DIAMETER_CODE
            ,-1,-1;NOMINAL_WALL_THICKNESS_CODE "NOMINAL_WALL_THICKNESS_CODE" true true false 254 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,NOMINAL_WALL_THICKNESS_CODE
            ,-1,-1;PIPE_LONG_SEAM_GCL "PIPE_LONG_SEAM_GCL" true true false 254 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,PIPE_LONG_SEAM_GCL
            ,-1,-1;DATE_INSTALLED "DATE_INSTALLED" true true false 36 Date 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,DATE_INSTALLED
            ,-1,-1;CONDITION_CODE "CONDITION_CODE" true true false 254 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,CONDITION_CODE
            ,-1,-1;GIRTH_WELD_GCL "GIRTH_WELD_GCL" true true false 254 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,GIRTH_WELD_GCL
            ,-1,-1;PCT100_SMYS_VAL "PCT100_SMYS_VAL" true true false 4 Long 0 5 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,PCT100_SMYS_VAL
            ,-1,-1;LINE_ID "LINE_ID" true false false 8 Double 0 16 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,LINE_ID
            ,-1,-1;DESIGNATOR "DESIGNATOR" true false false 10 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,DESIGNATOR
            ,-1,-1;LINE_DESCRIPTION "LINE_DESCRIPTION" true true false 254 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,LINE_DESCRIPTION
            ,-1,-1;LINE_NAME "LINE_NAME" true true false 299 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,LINE_NAME
            ,-1,-1;LINE_TYPE "LINE_TYPE" true false false 16 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,LINE_TYPE
            ,-1,-1;LINE_STATUS "LINE_STATUS" true false false 16 Text 0 0 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,LINE_STATUS
            ,-1,-1;BEG_ROUTE_ID "BEG_ROUTE_ID" true false false 8 Double 0 16 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,BEG_ROUTE_ID
            ,-1,-1;BEG_MEASURE "BEG_MEASURE" true false false 8 Double 2 12 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,BEG_MEASURE
            ,-1,-1;END_MEASURE "END_MEASURE" true false false 8 Double 2 12 
    ,First,#,Database Connections/OEDEVT.sde/PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV,END_MEASURE
            ,-1,-1""","#"
    )
print "Loaded R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV into memory"
```

**this is the error I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fyeboah/Desktop/Testing.py", line 69, in <module>
    ,-1,-1""","#"
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 2018, in TableToTable
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Rows: Dataset Database Connections\TRANSCO_OEDEVT.sde\PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (TableToTable).
```

Comment: Are you sure that "Database Connections\TRANSCO_OEDEVT.sde\PODSSDE.R_PIPE_SEGMENT_SV" exists and is a table file? I don't think that tool works on feature classes.

Comment: @Tom, Yes, it exists as a spatial_view.

Comment: then if it's a spatial view--as I said--it won't work with tabletotable. You need featureclasstofeatureclass.

Answer (score 1):

Two things....

1) In arcpy.Exists(SQLDEVGIS + "\R_TRANSCO_PIPES") the string "\R..." needs to be prefaced with an 'r' to denote that it is a raw string.  For example, should be:
arcpy.Exists(SQLDEVGIS + r"\R_TRANSCO_PIPES")

2) In this environment the _SV denotes a spatial view. If you are trying to copy featureclasses then use FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion

Comment: I added the preface 'r', but it is still giving me the same error. Could it be that I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Change from in_memory to the file system as a test.  All Transco pipe segments would be quite large in an in_memory workspace.  Could trim attributes off if this destination is necessary.  Also check memory as the process is occurring as another test.  I believe TableToTable is not the right tool anyway and should be FeatureClassToFeatureClass.